# Laravel 5.1 Seeding with Factories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying out the new Laravel 5.1 model factories to seed my app's tables.

Using the info on http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding#using-model-factories I built something like this:

```
// Account Model
class Account extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
    }

// Contact Model
class Contact extends Model
{ 
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }


// Account table seeder
$accounts = factory(App\Account::class(), 25)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $u->contacts()->save(factory(App\Contact::class)->make());
```

The problem is that the foreign key never gets properly set (the corresponding `account_id` that should be passed in to the `contact` table isn't being passed).

I tried setting the `account_id` manually like this:

```
$u->contacts()->save(factory(App\Contact::class)->make([
    'account_id' => $u->id,
]);
```

but this fails, and anyway it's not mentioned as needed in the docs.

Has anyone been using this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently since I used non-standard primary key names, I have to supply both the local and the foreign key columns.

Since I'd specified the primary key in the migration I thought that Laravel would pick up on that.

So to make this work you have to do the following in the model:

```
// Account Model
class Account extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'account_id', 'account_id');
    }
```

Once I did this the seeding worked as expected.